# 2016-10-05 security patch level breaks Nexus-9 Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I am getting the following crash on our application for only the Nexus 9 after the security update using Xamarin Forms 2.3.  It works fine for my Pixel-C, Samsung S2, Samsung Tab A and Dell Venue which is confusing me.  This only occurred after 2016-10-05 security patch.  I have 2 Nexus 9's and confirmed it was working prior to the patch.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
    10-24 23:36:50.460 13310 13310 D Mono    : Assembly Loader probing location: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/PlayerLync.AndroidLync/files/.__override__/System
.Linq.dll'.
10-24 23:36:50.461 13310 13310 D Mono    : AOT module '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/PlayerLync.AndroidLync/files/.__override__/System.Linq.dll.so' not found
: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/PlayerLync.AndroidLync-1/lib/arm/libaot-System.Linq.dll.so" not found
10-24 23:36:50.462 13310 13310 D Mono    : AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-armv7/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm
/System.Linq.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/PlayerLync.AndroidLync-1/lib/arm/libaot-System.Linq.dll.so" not found
10-24 23:36:50.462 13310 13310 D Mono    : Assembly Ref addref Java.Interop[0xe98ed740] -> System.Linq[0xe98ed0e0]: 2
10-24 23:36:50.462 13310 13310 D Mono    : Image addref System.Core[0xe98edb60] -> System.Core.dll[0xc5350400]: 1
10-24 23:36:50.463 13310 13310 D Mono    : Assembly System.Core[0xe98edb60] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
10-24 23:36:50.464 13310 13310 D Mono    : AOT module 'System.Core.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/PlayerLync.AndroidLync-1/lib/arm/libaot-
System.Core.dll.so" not found
10-24 23:36:50.465 13310 13310 D Mono    : AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-armv7/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm
/System.Core.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/PlayerLync.AndroidLync-1/lib/arm/libaot-System.Core.dll.so" not found
10-24 23:36:50.465 13310 13310 D Mono    : Config attempting to parse: 'System.Core.dll.config'.
10-24 23:36:50.465 13310 13310 D Mono    : Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-armv7/etc/m
ono/assemblies/System.Core/System.Core.config'.
10-24 23:36:50.465 13310 13310 D Mono    : Assembly Ref addref System.Linq[0xe98ed0e0] -> System.Core[0xe98edb60]: 2
10-24 23:36:50.465 13310 13310 D Mono    : Assembly Ref addref System.Core[0xe98edb60] -> mscorlib[0xdfbaa8a0]: 10
10-24 23:36:50.469 13310 13310 D Mono    : Assembly Ref addref Java.Interop[0xe98ed740] -> System.Reflection.Extensions[0xe98ed260]: 2
10-24 23:36:50.469 13310 13310 D Mono    : Assembly Ref addref System.Reflection.Extensions[0xe98ed260] -> mscorlib[0xdfbaa8a0]: 11
10-24 23:36:50.483 13310 13310 D Mono    : Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0xe98ed6e0] -> System.Core[0xe98edb60]: 3
10-24 23:36:50.484 13310 13310 D Mono    : DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
10-24 23:36:50.484 13310 13310 D Mono    : Searching for 'monodroid_typemap_managed_to_java'.
10-24 23:36:50.484 13310 13310 D Mono    : Probing 'monodroid_typemap_managed_to_java'.
10-24 23:36:50.484 13310 13310 D Mono    : Found as 'monodroid_typemap_managed_to_java'.
10-24 23:36:50.500 13310 13310 D Mono    : DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
10-24 23:36:50.500 13310 13310 D Mono    : Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_alloc_object'.
10-24 23:36:50.500 13310 13310 D Mono    : Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_alloc_object'.
10-24 23:36:50.500 13310 13310 D Mono    : Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_alloc_object'.
10-24 23:36:50.550 13310 13310 E mono-rt : Stacktrace:
10-24 23:36:50.550 13310 13310 E mono-rt :
10-24 23:36:50.550 13310 13310 E mono-rt :   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
10-24 23:36:50.550 13310 13310 E mono-rt :   at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.CreateDelegate (System.Delegate) <0x0014f>
10-24 23:36:50.550 13310 13310 E mono-rt :   at Java.Lang.Thread/IUncaughtExceptionHandlerInvoker.GetUncaughtException_Ljava_lang_Thread_Ljava_lang_Throwable_Ha
ndler () <0x00093>
10-24 23:36:50.550 13310 13310 E mono-rt :   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.RegisterJniNatives (intptr,int,intptr,intptr,int) <0x006db>
10-24 23:36:50.550 13310 13310 E mono-rt :   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_intptr_int_intptr_intptr_int (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
 <0x00137>
10-24 23:36:50.550 13310 13310 E mono-rt :   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
10-24 23:36:50.550 13310 13310 E mono-rt :   at (wrapper managed-to-native) Java.Interop.NativeMethods.java_interop_jnienv_alloc_object (intptr,intptr&,intptr)
<0x00043>
10-24 23:36:50.550 13310 13310 E mono-rt :   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment/Object.AllocObject (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference) <0x0004f>
10-24 23:36:50.550 13310 13310 E mono-rt :   at Java.Interop.JniType.AllocObject () <0x0003f>
10-24 23:36:50.550 13310 13310 E mono-rt :   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers/JniInstanceMethods.StartCreateInstance (string,System.Type,Java.Interop.JniArgumentV
alue*) <0x000bb>
10-24 23:36:50.550 13310 13310 E mono-rt :   at Java.Lang.Object..ctor () <0x00093>
10-24 23:36:50.550 13310 13310 E mono-rt :   at Android.Runtime.UncaughtExceptionHandler..ctor (Java.Lang.Thread/IUncaughtExceptionHandler) <0x00017>
10-24 23:36:50.550 13310 13310 E mono-rt :   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.Initialize (Android.Runtime.JnienvInitializeArgs*) <0x00a6b>
10-24 23:36:50.550 13310 13310 E mono-rt :   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_JnienvInitializeArgs* (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x000
cf>
10-24 23:36:50.550 13310 13310 E mono-rt :
10-24 23:36:50.550 13310 13310 E mono-rt : Attempting native Android stacktrace:
10-24 23:36:50.550 13310 13310 E mono-rt :
10-24 23:36:50.552 13310 13310 E mono-rt :      Could not unwind with `libunwind.so`: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/PlayerLync.AndroidLync-1/lib/arm/libunwi
nd.so" not found
10-24 23:36:50.552 13310 13310 E mono-rt :      Could not unwind with `libcorkscrew.so`: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/PlayerLync.AndroidLync-1/lib/arm/libc
orkscrew.so" not found
10-24 23:36:50.552 13310 13310 E mono-rt :
10-24 23:36:50.552 13310 13310 E mono-rt :      No options left to get a native stacktrace :-(
10-24 23:36:50.552 13310 13310 E mono-rt :
10-24 23:36:50.552 13310 13310 E mono-rt : =================================================================
10-24 23:36:50.552 13310 13310 E mono-rt : Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
10-24 23:36:50.552 13310 13310 E mono-rt : a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
10-24 23:36:50.552 13310 13310 E mono-rt : used by your application.
10-24 23:36:50.552 13310 13310 E mono-rt : =================================================================
10-24 23:36:50.552 13310 13310 E mono-rt :
10-24 23:36:50.552 13310 13310 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8 in tid 13310 (ync.AndroidLync)
10-24 23:36:50.553   184   184 W         : debuggerd: handling request: pid=13310 uid=10100 gid=10100 tid=13310
10-24 23:36:50.618 13327 13327 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-24 23:36:50.618 13327 13327 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'google/volantis/flounder:7.0/NRD91D/3234828:user/release-keys'
10-24 23:36:50.618 13327 13327 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
10-24 23:36:50.618 13327 13327 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
10-24 23:36:50.618 13327 13327 F DEBUG   : pid: 13310, tid: 13310, name: ync.AndroidLync  >>> PlayerLync.AndroidLync <<<
10-24 23:36:50.618 13327 13327 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8
10-24 23:36:50.619 13327 13327 F DEBUG   :     r0 c5137dd8  r1 00004001  r2 00000000  r3 c5137de8
10-24 23:36:50.619 13327 13327 F DEBUG   :     r4 00000008  r5 e3df427c  r6 00001f3c  r7 00000004
10-24 23:36:50.619 13327 13327 F DEBUG   :     r8 00001f38  r9 00000004  sl c5137dd8  fp ffb6d1b8
10-24 23:36:50.619 13327 13327 F DEBUG   :     ip e3df42c0  sp ffb6d188  lr e3c242fc  pc e3b96a60  cpsr 800e0010
10-24 23:36:50.620 13327 13327 F DEBUG   :
10-24 23:36:50.620 13327 13327 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
10-24 23:36:50.620 13327 13327 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 000dda60  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so
10-24 23:36:50.837   589 13328 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity PlayerLync.AndroidLync/md5872c6b6fe477e181c02853c0ea5fed3c.MainActivity
10-24 23:36:50.846   184   184 W         : debuggerd: resuming target 13310
```

Comment: I see that it is loading `armv7`, does your project have `arm64-v8a` ABI selected? (assuming that is a Dragon-based Tegra-K1 tablet if it is the dual-core version)

Comment: I have all 5 options selected under Supported Architectures.  Is this not correct?

Comment: @DaveFriedel did you find out what was causing this crash? I have a totally random crash on Nexus 9 with the *same* stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using sqlite in your application? We were getting similar crashes on our Nexus 9 after upgrading it to Android 7.0. It turned out that our custom sqlite library didn't have 64-bit file included. Even though the application includes arm64-v8a option, the 32-bit sqlite library forces the application to load armv7/32-bit libraries.

Once we rebuilt the custom sqlite library with 64-bit libsqlite.so file, and rebuilt the application with the new sqlite library, we are not getting crashes any more.

Please also check out the post from Xamarin about native library linking changes in Android 7.0.
https://blog.xamarin.com/preparing-for-native-library-linking-changes-in-android-n/

Comment: `Once we rebuilt the custom sqlite library with 64-bit libsqlite.so file, ` - What does this mean? Which library did you use?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem on Nexus 9 with Android 7.1. It's likely an Xamarin.Android issue; turning on AOT assemblies in `csproj`, it seems, fixes the crash:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    ...    
    <AotAssemblies>True</AotAssemblies>
    ...

</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I just saw this - sorry @Nikolai.  I was able to resolve this by only enabling "armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a under advanced tab.  I believe it was trying to use the 32bit version before which XPlatform stated above.  Note - I did have to track down random crashes but those oddly enough were cause by accessing the Background Downloader which uses the sqlite.  I then had to write my own downloader to remove those crashes - all of this nightmare was the result of the Nougat changes to the internal libraries.

Comment: @DaveFriedel Interestingly. I had already 64-bit libs in the APK. I knew for a fact that the app worked just fine on Nougat devices but Nexus9. Oddest thing is that this crash was absolutely random.
Only enabling AOT assemblies helped me.