# Android 7 + Xamarin.Forms in Release => Could not unwind with 'libunwind.so'

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I need to compile a Xamarin.Forms app that works fine with previous android version (6.x), but with latest Xamarin update and Visual Studio it do not works on Android 7.0 device.

At runtime I have that logcat:

```
11-07 21:33:26.887: E/mono-rt(22185): Could not unwind with libunwind.so: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/it.equipmentgroup.testlaneconnect-1/lib/arm/libunwind.so" not found
11-07 21:33:26.887: E/mono-rt(22185): Could not unwind with libcorkscrew.so: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/it.equipmentgroup.testlaneconnect-1/lib/arm/libcorkscrew.so" not found
11-07 21:33:26.955: A/DEBUG(22208): pid: 22185, tid: 22185, name: testlaneconnect >>> it.equipmentgroup.testlaneconnect <<<
11-07 21:33:26.956: A/DEBUG(22208): #00 pc 000dda60 /data/app/it.equipmentgroup.testlaneconnect-1/lib/arm/libmonosgen-2.0.so
11-07 21:33:27.196: W/ActivityManager(584): Force finishing activity it.equipmentgroup.testlaneconnect/md518d608c4cc7593a5d8f1b45905539da4.MainActivity
```

I read that blog post for native library support in Android Nougat and I set my Target API to Android 6.0 (23) but without success...

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: I am also seeing this error. very annoying, basically bricks my android 7 device for development

Answer (score 0):

Are you using sqlite or other system library in your application? Please see my answer in this post: [2016-10-05 security patch level breaks Nexus-9 Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40231377/2016-10-05-security-patch-level-breaks-nexus-9-xamarin/40498445#40498445)