# Xamarin app crashes with JNI RegisterNativeMethods error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Our Xamarin application has been tested extensively on many different devices. It seems to work just fine. However, on Nexus 9 running Android OS 7, it crashes immediately after starting up. There is an exception being thrown about JNI RegisterNativeMethods registering 0 native methods. I cannot put any try/catch block as the exception happens in a Xamarin owned background thread. The stack trace is at the end of this message.

What is interesting is the way we have been able to reproduce this problem. Under normal operation, the app runs fine. I can quit and re-run the app any number of times. To reproduce the problem, here is what we had to do:

1. Tap on "show all running apps" button at the bottom.
2. Click on the X button on the top-right of the window that shows the app. The app gets killed.
3. Now, click on the app icon to re-run it. You start getting the error.

I am wondering if anyone has any idea on what could be causing this problem.

The stack trace follows.

Regards,
Peter

```
01-10 15:25:40.102 W/art     ( 9586): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.WebViewRenderer
01-10 15:25:40.106 E/mono-rt ( 9586): Stacktrace:
01-10 15:25:40.106 E/mono-rt ( 9586): 
01-10 15:25:40.106 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at  
01-10 15:25:40.106 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1..ctor () [0x0001d] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:33
01-10 15:25:40.106 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ViewRenderer`2..ctor () 
01-10 15:25:40.106 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.WebViewRenderer..ctor () [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\WebViewRenderer.cs:15
01-10 15:25:40.106 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) 
01-10 15:25:40.106 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at  
01-10 15:25:40.106 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&) 
01-10 15:25:40.106 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (object,object[]) [0x00002] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:661
01-10 15:25:40.107 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (bool) [0x000ca] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/ReferenceSources/RuntimeType.cs:179
01-10 15:25:40.107 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow (bool,bool,bool,System.Threading.StackCrawlMark&) [0x0001a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/ReferenceSources/RuntimeType.cs:153
01-10 15:25:40.107 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor (bool,bool,bool,System.Threading.StackCrawlMark&) [0x0002a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/rttype.cs:5638
01-10 15:25:40.107 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type,bool) [0x00040] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:201
01-10 15:25:40.107 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/77cb8568/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:134
01-10 15:25:40.107 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Registrar`1.GetHandler (System.Type) [0x00015] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Registrar.cs:23
01-10 15:25:40.107 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Registrar`1.GetHandler (System.Type) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Registrar.cs:29
01-10 15:25:40.107 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x00006] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:288
01-10 15:25:40.107 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.AddChild (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement,Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer,Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererPool,bool) [0x00023] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:74
01-10 15:25:40.107 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement,Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x00104] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:207
01-10 15:25:40.107 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.Load () [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:58
01-10 15:25:40.107 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1.SetPackager (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager) [0x00007] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:334
01-10 15:25:40.107 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1.SetElement (TElement_REF) [0x00111] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:193
01-10 15:25:40.107 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x00027] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:126
01-10 15:25:40.107 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x0001f] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:289
01-10 15:25:40.107 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.AddChild (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement,Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer,Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererPool,bool) [0x00023] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:74
01-10 15:25:40.107 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement,Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x00104] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:207
01-10 15:25:40.107 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.Load () [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:58
01-10 15:25:40.108 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1.SetPackager (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager) [0x00007] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:334
01-10 15:25:40.108 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1.SetElement (TElement_REF) [0x00111] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:193
01-10 15:25:40.108 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x00027] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:126
01-10 15:25:40.108 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x0001f] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:289
01-10 15:25:40.108 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.AddChild (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement,Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer,Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererPool,bool) [0x00023] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:74
01-10 15:25:40.108 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement,Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x00104] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:207
01-10 15:25:40.108 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.Load () [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:58
01-10 15:25:40.108 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.FrameRenderer.OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs`1) [0x0008b] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FrameRenderer.cs:181
01-10 15:25:40.108 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.FrameRenderer.set_Element (Xamarin.Forms.Frame) [0x00018] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FrameRenderer.cs:63
01-10 15:25:40.108 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.FrameRenderer.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x00015] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FrameRenderer.cs:102
01-10 15:25:40.108 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x0001f] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:289
01-10 15:25:40.108 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.AddChild (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement,Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer,Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererPool,bool) [0x00023] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:74
01-10 15:25:40.108 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement,Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x00104] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:207
01-10 15:25:40.108 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.Load () [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:58
01-10 15:25:40.108 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1.SetPackager (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager) [0x00007] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:334
01-10 15:25:40.108 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1.SetElement (TElement_REF) [0x00111] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:193
01-10 15:25:40.108 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x00027] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:126
01-10 15:25:40.108 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x0001f] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:289
01-10 15:25:40.108 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.AddChild (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement,Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer,Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererPool,bool) [0x00023] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:74
01-10 15:25:40.108 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement,Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x00104] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:207
01-10 15:25:40.108 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.Load () [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:58
01-10 15:25:40.108 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1.SetPackager (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager) [0x00007] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:334
01-10 15:25:40.109 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1.SetElement (TElement_REF) [0x00111] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:193
01-10 15:25:40.109 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x00027] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:126
01-10 15:25:40.109 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x0001f] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:289
01-10 15:25:40.109 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.AddChild (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement,Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer,Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererPool,bool) [0x00023] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:74
01-10 15:25:40.109 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement,Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x00104] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:207
01-10 15:25:40.109 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.Load () [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:58
01-10 15:25:40.109 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1.SetPackager (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager) [0x00007] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:334
01-10 15:25:40.109 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1.SetElement (TElement_REF) [0x00111] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:193
01-10 15:25:40.109 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) [0x00027] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:126
01-10 15:25:40.109 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement,Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager) [0x00031] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Platform.cs:325
01-10 15:25:40.109 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.FragmentContainer.OnCreateView (Android.Views.LayoutInflater,Android.Views.ViewGroup,Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00008] in C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FragmentContainer.cs:66
01-10 15:25:40.109 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.n_OnCreateView_Landroid_view_LayoutInflater_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) 
01-10 15:25:40.109 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.6eff0615-3677-48f6-a5c8-9b75e08ae92c (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) 
01-10 15:25:40.109 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   at (wrapper native-to-managed) object.6eff0615-3677-48f6-a5c8-9b75e08ae92c (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) 
01-10 15:25:40.109 E/mono-rt ( 9586): 
01-10 15:25:40.109 E/mono-rt ( 9586): Attempting native Android stacktrace:
01-10 15:25:40.109 E/mono-rt ( 9586): 
01-10 15:25:40.113 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   Could not unwind with `libunwind.so`: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.hpe.myroom.vrg2.debug-1/lib/arm/libunwind.so" not found
01-10 15:25:40.113 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   Could not unwind with `libcorkscrew.so`: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/com.hpe.myroom.vrg2.debug-1/lib/arm/libcorkscrew.so" not found
01-10 15:25:40.113 E/mono-rt ( 9586): 
01-10 15:25:40.113 E/mono-rt ( 9586):   No options left to get a native stacktrace :-(
01-10 15:25:40.113 E/mono-rt ( 9586): 
01-10 15:25:40.113 E/mono-rt ( 9586): =================================================================
01-10 15:25:40.113 E/mono-rt ( 9586): Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
01-10 15:25:40.113 E/mono-rt ( 9586): a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
01-10 15:25:40.113 E/mono-rt ( 9586): used by your application.
01-10 15:25:40.113 E/mono-rt ( 9586): =================================================================
01-10 15:25:40.113 E/mono-rt ( 9586): 
01-10 15:25:40.113 F/libc    ( 9586): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8 in tid 9586
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this ticket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474484/android-7-xamarin-forms-in-release-could-not-unwind-with-libunwind-so).

Answer (score 1):

@Demitrian has pointed the right direction, the blog [Preparing for Native Library Linking Changes in Android N](https://blog.xamarin.com/preparing-for-native-library-linking-changes-in-android-n/) explain the reason why your app may crash on android 7.0 device.

From your exception message, it is possible that your `libunwind.so` lib and `libcorkscrew.so` lib are none-public libs, for now a set of libraries that see significant use—such as `libandroid_runtime.so`, `libcutils.so`, `libcrypto.so`, and `libssl.so` —are temporarily accessible on Android 7.0 (API level 24) for apps targeting API level 23 or lower.

You can directly refer to the official document: [NDK Apps Linking to Platform Libraries](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk).

> Starting in Android 7.0, the system prevents apps from dynamically linking against non-NDK libraries, which may cause your app to crash. This change in behavior aims to create a consistent app experience across platform updates and different devices. Even though your code might not be linking against private libraries, it's possible that a third-party static library in your app could be doing so.

Comment: Thank for your help. One thing I am not clear on. Why does it work fine the first time but stops working only after I kill the app and restart it? Regards.

Comment: @Peter, I considered this question when I wrote my answer yesterday too, I'm not the official support of google android, but from the document google provided, it says "which may cause your app to crash", I can only guess that using of private libs will not 100% make your app crash. And from your error message, your  `libunwind.so` lib and `libcorkscrew.so` cannot be found, this message fit the explanation in this doc. Maybe I'm wrong, but it's the best explanation I can found as a community member. To isolate device issue, I think you can try to run your app on other android 7.0 device.

Comment: Grace. I truly appreciate your help.